# How to specify WHERE-TO install a sub-installer within [Run] section and with "/Q" Parameter in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to specify WHERE-TO install a sub-installer within `[Run]` section and with `/Q` parameter in Inno Setup?

Example:

```
[Run]    
Filename: "{tmp}\app_name.exe"; Parameters: "/Q"; WorkingDir: "{app}\"; Components:language2;  Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist;
```

Thank you! )

Comment: The `app_name.exe` is an installer of another application, or what? What installer/application is that? How do we know what command-line parameters does it have?

Comment: yes, it's a custom installer made also with Inno Setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installers made with Inno Setup support these command-line parameters (among others):

> `/DIR="x:\dirname"`
>
> Overrides the default directory name displayed on the *Select Destination Location* wizard page. A fully qualified pathname must be specified. May include an "expand:" prefix which instructs Setup to expand any constants in the name. For example: '/DIR=expand:{pf}\My Program'.
>
> `/SILENT, /VERYSILENT`
>
> Instructs Setup to be silent or very silent. When Setup is silent the wizard and the background window are not displayed but the installation progress window is. When a setup is very silent this installation progress window is not displayed. Everything else is normal so for example error messages during installation are displayed and the startup prompt is (if you haven't disabled it with DisableStartupPrompt or the '/SP-' command line option explained above).

For details, see [Setup Command Line Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).

---

Also note that there's no `/Q` parameter. You probably want to use the `/SILENT` or the `/VERYSILENT` instead.

Comment: so if I want my program to be installed into my app folder I should use: `Parameters: "/VERYSILENT /DIR={app}`?

Comment: Correct, just make sure you enclose the `{app}` to double-quotes, in case the path contains spaces (like in "Program Files"): `Parameters: "/VERYSILENT /DIR=""{app}"""` See [Parameters in Sections](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params).